# Display all discombobulated, console login not working

Tags: upgrade

I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 16, didn't work properly... Tried again using console login and messed around with some Nvidia stuff, etc. Was working out problems and finding answers online. Now the display is all messed up--pixelated, way too big of font, almost in three sections... And console login has the same issues and will not load past bottom of screen. Help!! How on earth do I fix this?? It only works in recovery mode, and that really sucks.

Comment: The best solution is a fresh install with the proper Nvidia drivers if required. If you need help with that please ask a specific question and post your hardware specs.

Comment: Can I reinstall it using terminal in recovery mode?

Comment: A fresh install is like any other fresh install, from scratch and instead of an online upgrade.

Comment: I can't get the disc to run and reinstall ubuntu from the recovery mode... And it doesn't automatically come up when I reboot the computer.